# Taxonomy slug and page permalink with same name display items on custom page template - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-post-type, permalinks, taxonomy

Created custom page template, and when user makes new page, selects that template and category which is then displayed in that page - category and page permalink that have same name.

This is how my query looks like

```
    <?php query_posts( 'category_name=' . get_permalink() . '&post_status=publish,future' ); ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>
```

My question is, how would I do exact same thing but adding taxonomy? So on new page items would be shown by taxonomy category. Taxonomy name is photos_category.

Tried something like this but then nothing is displayed

```
<?php query_posts( 'post_type=photos' . 'taxonomy=photos_category' . get_permalink() . '&post_status=publish,future' ); ?>
```

By looking at first query that is working, I need to pass taxonomy name. How would I manage to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try get_posts to get all posts from a custom taxonomy:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'photos',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'taxonomy' => 'photos_category'
    ));
```

Codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: But wouldn't that just display all items on every page, not by category?

Comment: For that, i advice you to create custom archives files: archive-photos.php for your custom post type and taxonomy-photos_category.php for your custom taxonomy, then use the loop without query_posts. Check here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/